# Android Fragment Interface Unresponsive

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am having a strange issue with my program that I cannot explain and I have thus far not been able to find a solution. I have a simple activity that will switch between fragments and run the user through an initial setup of the app. The first fragment is just a text view at the top, with a button on the bottom with an onClickListener set to call a method on the parent activity, however in testing, when I click on the button, nothing happens. It does not change color like a normal button would, and no click seems to be registered.

Here is the XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/setup_intro" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:width="72dp"
    android:text="@string/next_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the fragment code where I implement the onClickListener

```
public class SetupFragmentInitialScreen extends SherlockFragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        View parentView = null; 
        parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup_fragment_initial_screen, 
                                      container, 
                                      false);

        Button nextButton = (Button)parentView.findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.v("ButtonPressed", "You Pressed the button!");
                ((InitialActivity)getActivity()).onInitialScreenNextPress();
            }
        });

        return parentView;
    }
}
```

And lastly, here is my code for my activity so far

```
public class InitialActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    private SetupFragmentInitialScreen initialScreen;
    private SetupFragmentPreferenceOneScreen preferenceOneScreen;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initialScreen = new SetupFragmentInitialScreen();
        preferenceOneScreen = new SetupFragmentPreferenceOneScreen();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, 
                                                android.R.anim.fade_out);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, 
                                    initialScreen);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    public void onInitialScreenNextPress()
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, 
                                                android.R.anim.fade_out);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, 
                                    preferenceOneScreen);

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

So far the code to me seems correct, but as I said, there is no reaction from the interface when I try to press the button.

Edit: I have added the following code to my Activity to check for touch events

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    Log.v("Touch Detected", "You are touching the screen.");

    return false;
}
```

It logs events all over the screen, except for when I'm touching the button, so the activity is receiving touch events, but the UI itself is not. I also tried loading another interface which has a pair of radio buttons, and they too were unresponsive. Is there something I'm doing wrong with initializing the fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it was. For whatever reason the program didn't like me trying to do the fade out-fade in animation when loading the first fragment into the activity. I removed that line from the onCreate() method and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of the code you posted seems to point to what the issue is.

A button does not need an onClick listener in order to change color when pressed, so I wouldn't worry about that part.  More importantly:

- Is it possible that any transparent view is lying on top of the button and taking the click?  DDMS has a "Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator" button that may help you check on this.
- Does your activity override dispatchTouchEvent(), onInterceptTouchEvent(), or related API's and could one of these be preventing the touch from reaching the button?
- If you are applying custom theming to the button, do you have separate visuals for the pressed state?

Comment: There shouldn't be any transparent views, the layout is just what I posted above, only 2 views in a relative layout, and I'm not inflating with anything special, just the fragment transaction calling replace android.R.id.content.

Likewise, there are no overrides, other than includes I have provided all of my activity code, and there is no custom theme involved, everything is stock.